# How to wrap html components in Vue 3 to make use of same event handlers?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, quasar-framework

This is the code:

```
<q-avatar @click="redirectToHome" rounded color="green">
  <img ... />
</q-avatar>
<q-toolbar-title @click="redirectToHome">
 App
</q-toolbar-title>
```

what I want is a dummy component `<></>` where I can wrap these two components and use event handlers only once. Something like this:

```
<what-to-put-here @click="redirectToHome">
<q-avatar rounded color="green">
  <img ... />
</q-avatar>
<q-toolbar-title>
 App
</q-toolbar-title>
</what-to-put-here>
```

Is this possible in Vue 3 ?

[EDIT]

Obviously using a `<div></div>` will mess up the styles

Comment: is the first code in a separate component?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper component which renders the slots and binds handlers on them.
Something like this

```
// WrapperComponent
setup(props, { slots }) { 
  return () => {
        if (slots.default)
          return slots.default({ prop: someProp })?.map((node, i) => h(node, { ref: `target-${i}`, ...attrs, onClick: $event => console.log('clicked', $event.target)}));
      };
  }
```